# InsertOrderedList doesn't make new list with marked text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I created a contenteditable div and added features for formatting.

One of the feature I added is creating a list from paragraph, I'll reproduce the steps below.

====

1) This is the paragraph I wanted part of it to be a list.
[image: this is the paragraph I wanted to make part of it a list]

2) So I marked the text to make it a list
, I use plugin from https://github.com/kenshin54/popline/ (modified it myself).

And it uses 
`document.execCommand("InsertOrderedList", false);`
for creating list
[image]

3) And then after I clicking the button, it made the whole paragraph to list. I just want the marked text to be (just for "Sed imperdiet....orci,")
[image]

The reason that I posting on Stackoverflow instead of Github repository issues (https://github.com/kenshin54/popline/) because I'm not sure that is an issue or not, I just want it to work like that.

Anyone has some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Bun, your answer doesn't work for me, but this does:

```
  var sel = rangy.getSelection();
  var range = sel.rangeCount ? sel.getRangeAt(0) : null;
  if (range) {
       var el = document.createElement("li");
       if (range.canSurroundContents(el)) {
           range.surroundContents(el);
           var ul = document.createElement("ul");
           range.surroundContents(ul);
       } else {
           alert("Unable to surround range because range partially selects a non-text node..");
       }
  }
```

(taken mostly from the rangy core demo)

Answer (score 0):

After long time of finding workarounds, kenshin (https://github.com/kenshin54) just saved my life.

He gave me this one http://jsfiddle.net/j83ueh6g

You can use `document.execCommand('insertOrderedList', false);` as the same way it works.